# 'django runserver' working fine but 'django runserver ip:port' giving 404

Tags: python, django

I understand similar questions have been asked but none of the solutions are applicable here.

When I run `python manage.py runserver`, everything works fine and I can access local server. But when I run `python manage.py runserver 10.5.51.56:8000` (local IP address of my machine), on doing browser request I receive 404 error(and requests comes to server).

After reading already asked questions on SO, I tried `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and now when I request `localhost:8000` through my browser I get correct response but when I request `10.5.51.56:8000` I again receive 404 with request coming to server.

I also tried with other ports (8001, 8002) in case port is being occupied but got same behaviour. I think it's some network permission issue but how can I pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Are you accessing this machine from the same network?

Comment: Have you added your IP 10.5.51.56 in ALLOWED_HOST in setttings.py file ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, I am doing this from same system only.

Comment: @RajSubit You don't need to set ALLOWED_HOST in debug mode

Comment: `When DEBUG is True and ALLOWED_HOSTS is empty, the host is validated against ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']`. This was changed in Django 1.10.3, 1.9.11, and 1.8.16 - [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-ALLOWED_HOSTS)

Comment: @rafalmp I added ALLOWED_HOST, but it didn't worked (version prior to ones mentioned here). Though nice point, didn't knew this

Comment: Can you please post your `urls.py` file(s)? Are you trying to hit the site root (`/`)?